# Can you leave a hyphen hanging when there is more than one adjective?

Tags: hyphenation

When you have 2 adjectives describing one object, do you use 2 hyphens? For example:

> There are short- and long-form publications.

Comment: Yes. That is the correct way to handle that. Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct

> General Principle 5
>
> When two or more compound modifiers have a common base, this base is sometimes omitted in all except the last modifier, but the hyphens are retained.

Examples:

> Long- and short-term memory
>
> 2-, 3-, and 10-min trials.

[apastyle.org](http://www.apastyle.org/learn/faqs/when-use-hyphen.aspx)